# fixture.whenStable() is stopped working/called after upgrading from Angular 4 to 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So I had few test cases which were checking some attributes of components (such as button).

Earlier I had test cases which used to working something like:

```
            fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
                const nextBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(
                    '#create-btn'
                );
                console.log(nextBtn)
                expect(nextBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');;
            })
```

suddenly, the code is not going inside `fixture.whenStable().then(() => {})`, the test cases are passing with a warning such as

> SomeComponent should have button disabled  has no expectations

I cant find anything over internet. Has anyone faced similar issue.

I also tried wrapping it around `async()` of `it` but no luck

Comment: you can try with `fakeAsync` function check this https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: Tried that as well, not working :(

Answer (score 3):

Try to add async to beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(async(() => { // <-- use async
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

Comment: It worked ! I was missing `async` on my second `beforeEach` !

Answer (score 2):

for angular 11 you can wrap beforeEach's  callback into [waitForAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync)
if you want to test somesing like `async ngOnInit`

```
 beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeFeatureComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things.

```
it('TEST', async(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges(); // you can write this
        const nextBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#create-btn');
        expect(nextBtn.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled')).toBe('true');
    });
}));
```